# Does OpenStack need s to have shared storage

Tags: bigdata, openstack

I'm new to OpenStack. Reading its documents I feel some of its features may need shared storages like SAN Storage. For example, the following paragraph says:

> **Block Storage**
>
> The optional Block Storage node contains the disks that
>   the Block Storage and Shared File System services provision for
>   instances.
>
> For simplicity, service traffic between compute nodes and this node
>   uses the management network. Production environments should implement
>   a separate storage network to increase performance and security.
>
> You can deploy more than one block storage node. Each node requires a
>   minimum of one network interface.

We have 4 servers that run some Big Data components like Apache Hadoop, Kafka, and Spark. We use virtual machines to run different components and the storage is just the server's local storage. We don't use any SAN Storage. So in such an environment (that we have no shared storage), can we use OpenStack's features?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct requirement to have shared storage to run Openstack, and if you are only using the most common Openstack components (e.g. nova, glance, neutron) you have nothing to worry about.

There may however be some components that assume that you have shared storage, and you may need to specifically disable it by configuration, or in some cases make modifications to the base templates for those components to work.

Comment: Thanks, How do you think to use the OpenStack to manage BigData VMs? Is it typical?

Comment: How about cinder and swift?

Comment: You are for sure not the only one running BigData using Openstack. There are even projects to help deploy things like Hadoop, e.g. https://github.com/openstack/sahara

Comment: You can use something like Ceph for Cinder, and Swift can use local storage.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani - Well ... they **are** shared storage, in a sense.  But they definitely can run off local disks.  Indeed, that is what you would do if you wanted good performance.